# Chromium OS for RPi2?

Tags: raspbian, chromium

**Hi**

Is Chromium OS for the Raspberry Pi ? I searched on Google and could not find it.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen any announcement of Chrome OS being made generally available for the Pi, nor is it listed on the Raspberry Pi's Foundations [download page](http://raspberrypi.org/downloads) .

Having said that I did find an old [bookmark](http://chromeos.hexxeh.net/) to a  project (no updates since 2013) that claimed to allow running Chrome OS on the Pi. Note that it appears to be inactive and the date would mean that there's likely to be no support for the newer Pi's B+ or model 2. More details and some clarifications can be found in this [forum thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/fancy-a-quake-iii-deathmatch/).